# MarkLogic search computed-buckets for age

Tags: marklogic, facet, bucket

I need to configure computed-buckets for a person age range constraint using an index for the birth date.  The bucketed age ranges are in the form 19-30, 31-40, 41-50, etc.  Since the possible anchor values are rather limited, I'm having trouble setting this up.  For example if today is 2019-01-01, for a 19-30 age range, I need to include birth dates from 1988-01-02 (the oldest 30 year old) to 2000-01-01 (the youngest 19 year old). How can I configure that computed-bucket?

For the "lt" attribute, if I use *lt="-P19Y"* I get less-than 2000-01-01, so 1999-12-31 is my last included birth date, thereby excluding those that turned 19 today.

And for the "ge" attribute, if I use *ge="-P31Y"*, I'm including the birth date of 1988-01-01 which is one day outside of my intended range, i.e., that person just turned 31 today.

If I could use "tomorrow" and "yesterday" as anchors, these values would work.  Or if I could specify a value like for the ge that means "minus 31 years plus 1 day", that would work too.  But I'm not sure how to make this work given the limitations.  Has anyone configured a person age constraint with buckets using a birth date index?

TIA

Comment: I've been pondering about this a bit, and I know there is start-of-day as anchor option, but no end-of-day as far as I know. I think you'd have to use a custom constraint that calculates bucket ranges on the fly. Doesn't have to be too difficult, but a little cumbersome..

Comment: Thanks @grtjn, sounds like, to be completely accurate, a custom constraint is necessary.  I would have thought age buckets would have been a common occurrence... surprised it is not supported better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "start-of-day" anchor option for computed buckets is what you're looking for.

```
  <constraint name="age">
    <range type="xs:date">
      <element name="birthdate"/>
      <computed-bucket name="18" ge="-P18Y" 
       anchor="start-of-day">18 and under</computed-bucket>
      <computed-bucket name="19-30" ge="P30Y" lt="-P18Y" 
       anchor="start-of-day">19 to 30</computed-bucket>
      <computed-bucket name="31-40" ge="-P40Y" lt="-P30Y" 
       anchor="start-of-day">31 to 40</computed-bucket>
      <computed-bucket name="41-50" ge="-P50Y" lt="-P40Y" 
       anchor="start-of-day">41 to 40</computed-bucket>
      <computed-bucket name="51" lt="-P50Y" 
       anchor="start-of-day">51 and older</computed-bucket>
    </range>
  </constraint>
```

The documentation can be found here:
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_22725

Edit: originally had the `ge` and `lt` attributes backwards for the desired buckets.

Comment: The edge case is off. end-of-day anchor would have given correct results, but that is not supported..